# Excel VBA Копирование заданного диапазона заданных листов в общий файл

Tags: excel, vba

В данный момент получается копировать заданные листы в нужный файл

```
Sub MakeDataset() 'Создает новую книгу файл с заданными листами
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim Dataset As Variant
    Dataset = Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A7")) 'Получаем из книги список листов для загрузки
    Sheets(Dataset).Copy       'копируем датасет в новый файл
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs wb.Path & "\Exit.xlsx" 'сохраняем/перезаписываем в каталоге рабочей книги
End Sub
```

А вот как копировать диапазоны заданных листов в нужный файл?
Например, последние 100 значений каждого листа

Comment: Копировать куда - в одну таблицу или на разные листы?  Данные каких столбцов копировать? По какому столбцу определять последнюю заполненную ячейку?

Comment: На разные листы. Всех. По любому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копируем листы, как и раньше. После этого удаляем лишние диапазоны строк:

```
Sub MakeDataset2()
    Dim aDataset()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim lRw As Long
    
    lRw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' последнее значение в столбце А'
    aDataset = Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A" & lRw))
    
    Call StartFinish(False)

    Sheets(aDataset).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs wb.Path & "\Exit.xlsx"
    Set wb = Nothing
    
    Call DelRows ' к уалению строк'
    Call StartFinish(True)
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub

' отключение/включение обновленияя экрана и собщений'
Sub StartFinish(bFlag As Boolean)
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = bFlag: .DisplayAlerts = bFlag: End With
End Sub
' удаление диапазонов строк'
Sub DelRows()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lRw As Long
   
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each sht In .Worksheets
            With sht
                lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1 ' последнее значение в столбце В'
            
                If lRw > 101 Then '  с учетом строки с шапкой таблицы'
                    .Rows("2:" & lRw - 100).Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next sht
    
        .Save: .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Показанное в коде определение последнего значения в столбце находит последнее видимое значение. Для гарантированного определения нужной строки предварительно нужно отобразить строки, скрытые автофильтром и скрытые вручную. Или можно использовать

```
With sht
    lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1 
    ' .................'
End With
```

Этот метод тоже имеет подводные камни. Если на листе есть строки без значений, но с форматированными ячейками, или в строках ранее были значения, то эти строки тоже попадают в пользовательский диапазон `.UsedRange`. В результате будут удалены строки выше, а "пустые" останутся.

Есть еще несколько методов определения нужной последней строки на листе и применять их нужно, исходя из конретной задачи и данных.